# Is there an option for Autofill in Google Drive Documents?

Tags: google-drive, word-processing, auto-form-fill

I use Google Drive Documents for word processing. There are several times where I write the same word or phrase in a document. Is there any way to set the Document to suggest an autofill of this word instead of me typing it multiple times?

Comment: I learned a lot about how to do it in spreadsheets.  If this were possible in your OS instead of in Google Docs, would that work as a solution?

Comment: I do believe so, I could manage if it was in the OS.